# people API google quota limits

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm looking into the People.API this is only for google+ users.

Does anyone know

1. How many queries can I ask a day/minutes for free? what are the General Quota limits?
2. How much will it cost to go beyond the threshold?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

There are two different People APIs, for both you can see the quotas in the cloud console:

1. Go to the corresponding API link:

   - G+ People API (only works for G+ users) https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/plus.googleapis.com/quotas
   - People API (works for all users) https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/quotas
2. Create or select a Google Cloud project
3. If the service is already enabled click **MANAGE** button, otherwise click **ENABLE** button to enable the service
4. Click **Quotas** tab

I'm not listing the explicit quotas and numbers because that may change over time and may be different depending on the client. Neither API charges for usage, if you go over the quota you will just be throttled. You can ask for more quota by:

1. Go into the quota tab
2. Click the pencil icon next to one of the quotas
3. Click the link *apply for higher quota*
4. Submit the form