# Sync Quota Exceeded: Where can I find my sync quota?

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

When using the `google-apis` `People API` I encountered a `"Sync Quota Exceeded"` error while executing requests to maintain an updated state of my contact list.  The request rate was once every 5 seconds.  I think I left it on overnight.

I remember reading (Though I can't find the source anymore in either [Calendar](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest) or [People](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync)) that requests with sync tokens have their own quota.  Where is that quota?  Can I request that it be raised?

If I go to all my Quotas in `IAM and Admin` I can see my `People API` quotas
And if I go to the `People API Usage`, I can see quotas, but not their usage.  I also see no mention of the `sync quota`.  Where can I find information about the Sync Quota?

```
People API  Critical read requests per minute per user          
People API  Critical write requests per minute per user         
People API  Write requests per minute per user          
People API  Read requests per minute per user
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [people API google quota limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700494/people-api-google-quota-limits)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I cannot find any reference to the Sync Token Quota in that link, or in the Cloud API link.

Answer (score 0):

the quota can be found in https://console.developers.google.com -> APIs & Services -> Library -> search People API -> click to Manage -> Quotas.

Comment: Are any of these for sync token requests sync token?  I was below the minimum default threshold (90 per minute for a single user) and still encountered the error, which makes me think it's not one of these quotas.